# Error using Async and await in C#

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I am new to C# and I am trying some examples. I have the below piece of code.

```
public async Task<string> RunSlowOperation()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Running the slow operation on thread id {0}",
                       Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    await Task.Delay(3000);
    Console.WriteLine("Slow operation about to finish with thread id {0}",
                       Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); 

    return "This operation is very slow";
}
```

In my main function, I am invoking this async method using Task but getting errors:

```
Operation op = new Operation();
Task<string> t = new Task<string>(() => op.RunSlowOperation());
```

Errors displayed for above:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a
>   delegate type Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>'` to 'string'

Answer (score 2):

`RunSlowOperation` returns a `Task<string>`. When you instansiate your `Task`, you tell the compiler the return type is a `string`, which it isn't, hence why the compiler is yelling at you.

You have a couple of options to achieve what you want. First is to tell the compiler you're returning a `Task<Task<string>>` instead of a `Task<string>`:

```
Task<Task<string>> t = new Task<Task<string>>(() => RunSlowOperation());
```

The other, which seems more likely to me as what you're *actually* trying to do, is simply `await` on `RunSlowOperation`:

```
public async Task FooAsync()
{
    string result = await RunSlowOperation();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Third, would be to use [`Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `new Task`, which is the recommended approach to queueing work to the thread-pool when using the TPL. `Task.Run` is aware of a async delegates and will unwrap the inner task for you, without needing to do it yourself, hence why the compiler allows to assign it to a `Task<string>`:

```
Task<string> x = Task.Run(() => RunSlowOperation());
```

And if you want to asynchronously wait on it:

```
string t = await Task.Run(() => RunSlowOperation());
```

Comment: The first two approaches worked fine. However, I am facing issues with the last approach. I tried as below:
    `Task<string> t = Task<string>.Run(op.RunSlowOperation);`
This gives below warning:
    `The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run<string>(System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>>)' and 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(System.Action)'`

Am I missing something here? I even tried the way you mentioned in your answer. That also throws the same error.

Comment: @vmn You're right, for some reason LINQPad didn't scream at me when I used a method group conversion. I've edited the code examples.

Comment: Thanks. It worked fine. I am new to C# and finding it difficult to acquaint myself to these syntactical intricacies. Can you suggest some good articles that focus on these?

Comment: @vmn Which syntactical intricacies are you referring to?

Comment: The one of lambda expressions, delegates, anonymous functions , various ways of defining and running Tasks.

Also, in the fist approach where we used `Task<Task<string>>`, how do we extract the result string. `t.Result` is not giving proper value.

Comment: @vmn In that case you need `t.Result.Result`, since you have a nested task. I suggest you search google for those terms, you'll see lots of blog posts and MSDN articles which can give you a preliminary intro to those topics.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you creating a new Task in your main function? You can already await the Task method you have created.

Just do this in your main function:

```
Operation op = new Operation();
string t = await op.RunSlowOperation();
```

Don't forget to make your main function *async*

Answer (score 1):

You must await your method from the Main.

```
Operation op = new Operation();
Task<string> t = await op.RunSlowOperation();
```

But it is a bad practise to await a method in Main, instead of this create a method like this

```
static async void MyMethod()
{
            Operation op = new Operation();
            Task<string> t = await op.RunSlowOperation();
}
```

and than call this method from your Main method.For more see
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx and
there are good videos for begginer.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMcycFie-nk

Comment: But an async method returning void is not a good practice. An async method should either return Task or Task<T>.

Comment: you are right, I have only said for this case.Because if you return Task you must also await in Main.Only for this case :)